# Combining table content while 'excluding' given columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I want to combine with each other. At this point I'm using UNION to combine them which works perfectly well for all my needs but for one thing. Since UNION replaces everything in T1 with T2, T3.votes would be 0. But I don't want it to be 0 - I want it to keep the state of T1.votes (don't mind that T2 are only four rows long as I've managed to union these together but I just don't get T3.votes to show the T1.votes content).

How do I accomplish this? Clarification: everything should be combined except T2.votes.

```
T1     
+-----------+-------+---------------+
| CANDIDATE | VOTES | RANKED_CHOICE |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
|         1 |     8 |             0 |
|         2 |     1 |             0 |
|         3 |     2 |             0 |
|         4 |     4 |             0 |
|         5 |     2 |             0 |
|         6 |     3 |             0 |
+-----------+-------+---------------+

T2
+-----------+-------+---------------+
| CANDIDATE | VOTES | RANKED_CHOICE |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
|         2 |     0 |             4 |
|         3 |     0 |             1 |
|         4 |     0 |             2 |
|         5 |     0 |             1 |
+-----------+-------+---------------+

COMBINED TABLE AS I EXPECT IT TO BE (T3)
+-----------+-------+---------------+
| CANDIDATE | VOTES | RANKED_CHOICE |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
|         1 |     8 |             0 |
|         2 |     1 |             4 |
|         3 |     2 |             1 |
|         4 |     4 |             2 |
|         5 |     2 |             1 |
|         6 |     3 |             0 |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If all candidates of T1 are in T2, you can do a left join.

```
select t1.candidate, max(t1.votes,ifnull(t2.votes,0)), max(t1.ranked_choice,ifnull(t2.ranked_choice,0))
from t1 left join t2
on t1.candidate = t2.candidate;
```

Else you can do a union of T1 and T2 as a subquery and fetch the sum or maximum of votes from this subquery.

```
select candidate, sum(votes),max(ranked_choice) from
(
select candidate,votes,ranked choice from t1
union
select candidate,votes,ranked choice from t2
) sub
group by candidate;
```

Edit: There were two minor bugs in my queries - use greatest() instead of max() and an underscore between "ranked choice":

```
select t1.candidate, greatest(t1.votes,ifnull(t2.votes,0)) as votes, greatest(t1.ranked_choice,ifnull(t2.ranked_choice,0)) as rank
from t1 left join t2
on t1.candidate = t2.candidate;

select candidate, sum(votes),max(ranked_choice) from
(
select candidate,votes,ranked_choice from t1
union
select candidate,votes,ranked_choice from t2
) sub
group by candidate;
```

Both queries yield the desired result.

Comment: Do this really leave T1.votes in its original state?